# How to specify when to return output of the function

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following function:

```
function result=myfun(varargin)    
result=[];    
myFig=figure();    
B1=uicontrol(myFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','done','Callback',{@done_Callback});    

    function done_Callback(varargin)  
        result =10;
        delete(mainFig);
    end
end
```

I am trying to only return output after the button callback is executed. Right now it returns an empty variable right away. I know how to do this in guide GUIs but all of my project is written without guide. I am assuming I need uiwait somewhere, but not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `uicontrol` only generates the button, it doesn't wait for it to be pressed. Otherwise, a full GUI with several elements would not be possible – you couldn't insert another element before the first hadn't been activated, and afterwards the first one could not be activated any longer. For this reason, GUI callbacks are executed in another thread than the main Matlab program, namely in the "event queue".

If you want your program to wait until the button is pressed, you have to program this explicitly:

```
function result=myfun(varargin)    
result=[];    
myFig=figure();    
B1=uicontrol(myFig,'Style','pushbutton','String','done','Callback',{@done_Callback});    
while isempty(result)
    drawnow
end

    function done_Callback(varargin)  
        result =10;
        fprintf('hi\n')
        delete(myFig);
    end
end
```

The `drawnow` is there to tell Matlab it should allocate execution time to the event queue, which is not normally done when Matlab is busy, e.g. with running a `while` loop.

For (slightly) more information, have a look at [How Does a GUI Work?](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/how-does-a-gui-work.html) and [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. This does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I just edited the answer once more, maybe you find the additional information interesting.